# how can I set the log4j conversionpattern at runtime

Tags: java, log4j

I have a Java app while parses input from a spreadsheet. I've added the ability to run just the parser part standalone from an ant task. However the normal log4j pattern I'm using can make the output hard to read, I'd like to set a simple pattern at runtime.

So something like `log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %m%n`

```
        parseDebug = new Boolean(System.getProperty("ptpunit.parseDebug")).booleanValue();

        if(parseDebug){

            // SET CONVERSION PATTERN HERE

            log.setLevel((Level) Level.DEBUG);

        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
ConsoleAppender a = (ConsoleAppender) Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("stdout");
a.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d{HH:mm:ss}  %-5.5p  %t %m%n"));
```

Of course you have to change the Appender type according to the one you are using and you may have to replace "Logger.getRootLogger()" by the a call to fetch the logger your appender is actually attached to.

Comment: Doesn't look like this is possible with log4j2. While you can getLayout() on an Appender, you can't setLayout().
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/Appender.html